# Python bisect: pass value instead of returning insertion index

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using the binary search function mentioned here: [When are bisect_left and bisect_right not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297249/when-are-bisect-left-and-bisect-right-not-equal), but instead of returning False, I want to just skip values that aren't in the list `e`.

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def binsearch(l,e):
    index = bisect_left(l,e)
    if index == len(l) or l[index] != e:
        return False
    return index

l = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
e = [7, 9, 2, 4, 7]
index = []

for i in e:
   index.append(binsearch(l,i))

print index # [4, 6, 1, False, 4]
```

I tried replacing `return False` with `pass` but am getting the index of where the value not in the list would be placed. Is there a way to simply pass a value if it is not in `l` and output `[4, 6, 1, 4]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the `return` with a `pass` in the `if` statement, it's as if the `if` didn't exist. That's why you get an index returned.

What you can do instead is return either a sentinel value or a tuple combining the index with a `True`/`False` indicator of whether the item was found.

Sentinel style:

```
if index == len(l) or l[index] != e:
    return -1
return index
```

Tuple style:

```
if index == len(l) or l[index] != e:
    return False, None
return True, index
```

To complete the picture you need to put some logic into the spot where you're building the final list. Example for the tuple form:

```
for i in e:
    found, ind = binsearch(l,i)
    if found:
        index.append(ind)
```